# Wie sagt man " to shed light onto sth" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, verb-choice

> Ich brauche Hilfe bei der deutschen Präpositionen. Du kannst wahrscheinlich Aufschluß
>   über diesem Problem geben.

```
 I need help with german prepositions. You can probably shed a light on this problem.
```

Comment: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences please try to boil down your sentence a bit and describe where you got problems, or at least not make the problem you have into the example sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Licht ins Dunkel bringen

Example:

> Wir kamen lange nicht weiter, aber dann kam unser Chef und hat Licht ins Dunkel gebracht. Endlich konnten wir das Problem lösen.

Translated:

> We were stuck, but then came our boss, he shed some light (onto the problem). Finally we were able to solve the problem.